# Sequence auto generate function using JavaScript and node with mongo

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

am new to JavaScript and I need to generate a sequence of 5 digit numbers with an alphabet being the 1st character (for ex:  A00001). [totally it will be 6 letters with alphabet] and the sequence should go till A99999 and after that it should switch to alphabet B and start with B00000 and end with B99999 and this should go on till alphabet Z. Can anyone pls help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var num = 0
var char = 'A'

while(true){
    console.log(char+('00000'+num).slice(-5))
    num += 1
    if(num>=100000){
        num=0
        char=String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt() + 1)
        if(char.charCodeAt()>90)
            break
    }
    
}
```

If you want to create a new id using the previous id it can be done as done below:

```
var prev_id = 'A05786'

num = parseInt(prev_id.slice(1))

char = prev_id[0]

num += 1
if(num>=100000){
    num=0
    char=String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt() + 1)
}

new_id = char+('00000'+num).slice(-5)
console.log(new_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But what if I store the first sequence like A00001 in database and next I need it to increment to A00002 based on the previous database value. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You could use`db.collection_name.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)` to get the previous id and then use the logic I mentioned in the answer to generate the next id

Comment: Hi JEFFRIN JACOB, I can retrieve previously saved data from the database, but how can I increase the value based on the prior database value and save it?

Comment: i have edited the answer to do what you have asked for

Comment: 2022-23/A00001 can you help me out store like this